# How to properly load/move jquery in footer of WP theme?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm trying to load jquery in footer of my WP theme (WP 3.8), but non of solution which I try didn't work for me. I have search all over the net, but didn't find correct way to load jquery in the footer of WP theme.

This is my `function.php`:

```
if (!is_admin())
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);

function my_jquery_enqueue() {

    // Deregister the included library
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    // Register the library again from Google's CDN
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js", false, '1.10.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

And this JS is correctly loaded in the footer using this in my `function.php` as well:

```
/* Integrate preloader script */
wp_register_script('jPreloader', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/loader.js', 'jquery', null, true);
wp_enqueue_script('jPreloader');

wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );

/*
    * Register and enqueue a script that does not depend on a JavaScript library.
    */

function child_add_scripts() {

    wp_register_script(
        'avia',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/avia.js',
        array('jquery'),
        '1.1',
        true
        );

    wp_register_script(
        'bottom',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bottom.js',
        array('jquery'),
        null,
        true
        );

    wp_enqueue_script('avia');
    wp_enqueue_script('bottom');
}

// Run this function during the wp_enqueue_scripts action
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_add_scripts' );
```

Don't know why jQuery isn't loaded in the footer of my WP theme, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the `wp_footer()` hook at the end of your `<body>`?

Comment: there is an plugin for WP, that moves all JS or jQuery to the footer automatically, i think it is called Javascript to Footer

Comment: Yes, I have wp_footer() hook.

Comment: I think that I have solve the problem with wp plugin - Scripts to Footer (http://wordpress.org/plugins/scripts-to-footerphp/). 

And I have change order of loading scripts in my function.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (!is_admin())
    add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);

function my_jquery_enqueue() {

    // Deregister the included library
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    // Register the library again from Google's CDN
    $googleScript = 'http'. ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js';
    wp_register_script('jquery', $googleScript, false, '1.10.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Comment: I have try, but still for a second show countdown timer and other content and then preloader animation. Any idea, how to proper make this preloader?

Answer (score 2):

I have use this function to move jquery to footer:

```
function custom_clean_head() { 
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts'); 
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9); 
   remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);

   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
   add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5); 
} 

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_clean_head' );
```

But, I need solution for my preloader which I have on my test site here: http://dev.bogosavljev.com/

Can somebody take a look, and tell me what i have done wrong?

Problem is that content on page is shown for a sec., and then my preloader (animated letter B) is shown, and after that with fade effect, it's shown page.

How to show first preloader (/js/loader.js), and then the page? 
For reference I have use Adham site which have same effect - http://www.adhamdannaway.com/

Comment: Beware when using this code. It moves every script enqueued to the head to the footer, which is likely to break any plugins that expect or require the script up top.

Comment: You are right, but how then to make proper content preloader?